# Backbone.js Timer - useless setInterval call

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

Although I searched for a solution, i did not found one for my problem. Im using cordova and jquery mobile. there are fired to events: document.ready and the device ready of cordova. i want to check the loading states by checking to booleans, to know when to start the main application.

so have a look at my code:

First: The first js-File loaded:

```
function checkReadyStates() {
    if(domReady && cordovaReady) {
        timer.stop();
        start();
    }
}

var domReady = false;
var cordovaReady = true;
var timer = new TimerModel({interval : 50, method : checkReadyStates});
timer.start();

// get notified when DOM is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    ConsoleController.info('Document ready.');
    domReady = true;
});

// get notified when cordova is ready
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    ConsoleController.info('Cordova loaded.');
    cordovaReady = true;
}, false);
```

Second: The TimerModel:

```
define(['backbone'],function(Backbone) {

var model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        timerObject : null,
        active : false,
        interval : 1000,
        method : null,
    },

    // init timer
    initialize : function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'start', 'stop'); // context bindings
    },

    // starts the timer with given interval
    start : function() {
        if(!this.active) {
            this.active = true;
            this.timerObject = setInterval(this.method, this.interval);
        }
    },

    // stops timer
    stop : function() {
        this.active = false;
        clearInterval(this.timerObject);
    }

});

// return the timer model
return model;

});
```

Hope someone's able to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line of code here

```
this.timerObject = setInterval(this.method, this.interval);
```

Both `this.method` and `this.interval` are `undefined`, so you're setting *nothing* running *never*. The reason for this is that `Backbone.Model` doesn't define the properties passed in the constructor on the instance itself, but in an internal property called `attributes`. You can access the attributes using the `model.get(property)` method:

```
this.timerObject = setInterval(this.get('method'), this.get('interval'));
```

Furthermore it doesn't really make sense to define the timer as a model. No doubt you'll get it to work, but it's not what `Backbone.Model`is intended for. Models are used to represent a piece of `data`, not functionality. I think a simple function would serve you better here.

**Edit:** To rephrase, models are not *just* for data, but they should contain data. The model is a good place to define functions (methods) that operate on that data. Your `TimerModel` on the other hand is pure logic - it doesn't represent or encapsulate any data or state. I feel that logic is better encapsulated as a simple function "class":

```
var Timer = function(options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.active = false;
    this.interval = options.interval || 1000;
    this.method = options.method || null;


    // starts the timer with given interval
    this.start = function() {
        if(!this.active) {
            this.active = true;
            this.timerObject = setInterval(this.method, this.interval);
        }
    };

    // stops timer
    this.stop = function() {
        this.active = false;
        clearInterval(this.timerObject);
    };

    _.bindAll(this, 'start', 'stop')
});
```

Usage:

```
var timer = new Timer({interval: 50, method:checkReadyStates});
```

Comment: But when models are only storing the data, where to put functions working on that data?

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much. I see your point with the model thing but for me a Timer is a model too, as it is an abstract thing to use.

Comment: @tellob, you're welcome. As I said, the model will work fine too, so go for it by all means, if it feels right to you.